# On clicking on any username from the table, a modal will apper and will show the activity of users which has been fetched from the api. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

[image: User Details Table]

I have created a mock server get api. It is returning the following JSON data.

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "members": [{
            "id": "W012A3CDE",
            "real_name": "Egon Spengler",
            "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "activity_periods": [{
                    "start_time": "Feb 1 2020  1:33PM",
                    "end_time": "Feb 1 2020 1:54PM"
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "Mar 1 2020  11:11AM",
                    "end_time": "Mar 1 2020 2:00PM"
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "Mar 16 2020  5:33PM",
                    "end_time": "Mar 16 2020 8:02PM"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "W07QCRPA4",
            "real_name": "Glinda Southgood",
            "tz": "Asia/Kolkata",
            "activity_periods": [{
                    "start_time": "Feb 1 2020  1:33PM",
                    "end_time": "Feb 1 2020 1:54PM"
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "Mar 1 2020  11:11AM",
                    "end_time": "Mar 1 2020 2:00PM"
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "Mar 16 2020  5:33PM",
                    "end_time": "Mar 16 2020 8:02PM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My UserTable component code is

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UserModal from './UserModal';

class UserTable extends UserModal {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            showModal: false,
            temp: {
                id: null
            }
        }
    }

    getUserDetailsFromMockApi = () => {
        fetch('https://79a4a7a3-1373-4441-9fea-2a4b9ca78214.mock.pstmn.io/users', { method: 'GET' })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ users: data.members })
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUserDetailsFromMockApi();
    }

    toggleModal = (id) => {
        debugger;
        if (this.state.showModal === false)
            this.setState({ showModal: true });
        else if (this.state.showModal === true)
            this.setState({ showModal: false });

      this.showSelectedUserActivity(id);
    }

    renderTd = () => {
        let tdDiv = this.state.users.map((user, index) => {
            return (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{user.id}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" onClick={() => { this.toggleModal(user.id); this.state.temp.id = user.id }}>{user.real_name}</a></td>
                    <td>{user.tz}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        });

        return tdDiv;
    }

    showSelectedUserActivity = (id) => {
        debugger;

        let userDetails = this.state.users.filter((user) => id === user.id);

        // return (
        // <Modal isOpen={this.state.showModal} toggle={this.toggleModal}>
        //     <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal}>Selected User Activity Details</ModalHeader>
        //     <ModalBody>{userDetails[0]}</ModalBody>
        //     <ModalFooter>
        //         <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggleModal}>Cancel</Button>
        //     </ModalFooter>
        // </Modal>
        // )

        return <UserModal
            isOpen={this.state.showModal}
            toggle={this.toggleModal}
            userDetails={userDetails}
            onClick={this.toggleModal}
        />
    }

    render() {
       
         let userId = this.state.users.map((user, index) => user.id);

        return (
            <>
                <div className="main-div container">
                    <h2 className="text-center">User Details</h2>

                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Time Zone</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {this.renderTd()}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

                {this.showSelectedUserActivity(userId)}

            </>
        )

    }
}
export default UserTable;
```

My UserModal Component code is

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

class UserModal extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            ...this.props
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen} toggle={this.props.toggle}>
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.onClick}>Selected User Activity Details</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>{this.props.userDetails[0]}</ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.props.onClick}>Cancel</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
        )
    }
}

export default UserModal;
```

I can able to show the data on the table, and on clicking any username a modal is opening, but data is not showing inside the modal.

The requirement is that on clicking on any user, a modal should open which displays all the time ranges during which they were active on that day, with an option to view all the periods of activity for different days using a calendar.

I am looking for a solution using React and vanilla javascript.